# Multi threading with ObservesProperty

Tags: c#, prism

I have command like this:

```
CancelCommand = new DelegateCommand(Cancel, () => IsProcessing).ObservesProperty(() => IsProcessing);
```

And in other method I call

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                IsProcessing = true; // Stop here
                IsProcessing = false;
            });
```

Somehow the execution stops when `IsProcessing` set to `true`. But when I change to

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => IsProcessing = true);
IsProcessing = false; // Hit this line then stop again
int i = 0; // Never reach here
```

Looks like `ObservesProperty` causes problem when `IsProcessing` set in not UI thread. Is it bug or works as designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not unique to Prism. All Prism does it hook up to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` of the property you specified and invoke the `CanExecuteChanged` event.

The event `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` can cause changes to UI elements (such as change the value of a button's `IsEnabled` property) - so it must be invoked from a UI thread. Unlike the binding engine, it does not do this automatically.

You should either:

- Set the property from the UI thread before/after starting your thread. Using async/await would make that very easy:

  ```
  async Task DoStuff() // start this method from the UI thread
  {
      IsProcessing = true;
      try
      {
          await Task.Run(() => { ... });
      }
      finally
      {
          IsProcessing = false;
      }
  }
  ```
- Use `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`. Do **not** use `Invoke` - that's just wasting a thread waiting for the UI to complete.